# before action search and replace RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue in a Rails app where I need to search and replace certain characters before they hit any controller actions.

For example a right single quote (’) I want to universally replace with a single quote, same goes for left/right double quotes, I want to replace just with regular double quotes. Also, HTML (nbsp)   I want to replace with an empty space.

I know how to do this in individual actions and before-save's, but doing this per model and field becomes complex. It would be nice to search and replace the body before it gets parsed into a hash.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about replacing characters in parameters before saving them to the database?

Comment: yes, but across all models... ideally it woudn't just be the before save, it would be before it hits any controller actions

Comment: Put a before_filter at the top of application_controller to process params.  This should get done before any other filters or actions.  You could also find the method inside rails which builds `params` from the request, and monkey patch it.  This is possibly frowned upon and also possibly risky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For controllers, there are `before_filter`s (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter).

You could define a global `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` and iterate (and edit) the `params` hash.

But, nevertheless, it sounds as if you should think about *why* there are unwanted unicode characters in your params instead of how to replace them *afterwards*.

*Edit:*

Another option would be to create a custom middleware. Take a look at the following links:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware?view=asciicast
- https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/List-of-Middleware

Comment: I guess the middleware layer would be the easier to go with, thanks.